# Java Editor Software

Tags: java, awt

I am creating an editor using java in which my find and replace option fails while I am replacing c++ with java then after replacing my code shows java++ it does not replace ++ completely into the text files.

So here are the find methods I created in my code using patcher and matcher

```
public void findingValue1() {

    p = Pattern.compile(p.quote(tf1.getText()));
    m = p.matcher(tavalue);

    if (m.find(x)) {
        y = 0;
        char ch[] = tavalue.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.start(); i++)
            if (ch[i] == '\n')
                y++;
        ta.select(m.start() - y, m.end() - y);
        r1 = m.start() - y;
        r2 = m.end() - y;
        x = m.end();
        user = true;
    } else
        cannotFound();
    f1.toFront();
}

public void findingValue2() {
    try {
        s1 = ta.getText();
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("\r", "");
        ta.setText(s1);
        ta.setCaretPosition(pos);
        p = Pattern.compile(tf2.getText());
        m = p.matcher(s1);
        if (m.find(pos)) {
            ta.requestFocus();
            ta.select(m.start(), m.end());
            String str1, str2;
            str1 = tf3.getText();
            str2 = tf2.getText();
            if (str1.length() > str2.length())
                pos = m.end() + 1;
            else
                pos = m.start() + 1;
        } else
            cannotFound();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        cannotFound();
    }

}
```

I know that is not the proper way to ask questions but my code is very huge.
Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: can i need to shows the full code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
>         p=Pattern.compile(tf2.getText());
> ```

... uses the text entered into `tf2` is a *regular expression* to match.  The `+` character is one of several that have special meaning in regular expressions.  If you want to treat the user input as literal text, regardless of what characters it contains, then you need to quote it or otherwise so indicate.  For example,

```
        p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(tf2.getText()));
```

Comment: sir it stills not works for me.. When I replace java into c++ its replaces only c I.e... Java ++

Comment: Sir when I try it with some digits like replacing 111 with AAA then it is successfully working